Show two fusion guage chats overlay each other
I have requirement to show two fusion guage charts in same place like rainbow,
any idea how to do that as per the screenshot
I tried to show the two fusion charts in same place, but i can show only one and another one is hiding behind that.

I want to acheive as like this image
I tried something like this, one is hiding another
<div>
          <div class="relative">
            <fusioncharts class="absolute inset-0" width="700" height="400" type="angulargauge" [dataSource]="dataSource">
            </fusioncharts>
            <div class="absolute inset-0" id="gauge2">
              <fusioncharts class="absolute inset-0" width="700" height="400" type="angulargauge" [dataSource]="dataSource1">
              </fusioncharts>
            </div>
<!--            <fusioncharts class="absolute inset-0" width="700" height="400" type="angulargauge" [dataSource]="dataSource1">-->
<!--            </fusioncharts>-->
          </div>
        </div>

